# Phonegap input focus

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

I want to create a form for my Phonegap app on android. When an input field is filled the focus must move to the next input field.

Well this worked but when I type something in the next input field the value appends to previous input field. I have to touch with my finger on the input to change it.

In my browser and the android simulator it worked well but not on the app on my phone.

Is there another way to do this?